# Increase Volume of a specific mxf channel with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a MXF file with 6 mono channel (part of a 5.1 mix), How can I create a new mxf increasing the volume of the third (center) channel without reencoding video and the other audio channels?

Answer (score 1):

The command template would be,

```
ffmpeg -i in.mxf -map 0 -c copy -filter:a:2 volume=2 -c:a:2 pcm_s16le out.mxf
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should “accept” the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).